# Injecting jQuery namespace into AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, requirejs

I'm having a bit of a trouble here.

I'm using RequireJS to load my modules and dependencies.
I am trying to avoid polluting the global namespace, so I am using the following configuration as a starting point, to avoid defining `$` or `jQuery` in the global window object:

```
require.config({
    map: {
       '*': { 'jquery': 'jquery-no-conflict' },
       'jquery-no-conflict': { 'jquery': 'jquery' }
    },
    shim: {
       'jquery': { exports: 'jQuery' },
       'angular': { exports: 'angular', deps: ['jquery'] }
       // ...
    }
});
```

The module `jquery-no-conflict` would look like this:

```
define('jquery-no-conflict', ['jquery'], function (jQuery) {
    return jQuery.noConflict(true);
});
```

This apparently solves the issue, but there is a problem.

I was not aware that there is some AngularJS behavior that is different wether jQuery is loaded or not, and apparently, this is done by inspecting the global namespace.

For instance, AngularJS `$window` would be a wrapper of the native element `window` if no jQuery is found or loaded, but it would be a wrapper of jQuery's `$(window)` if jQuery is defined.

For some functionality on my website, I need the latter, but with this configuration, I am getting the former (because AngularJS does not seem to find jQuery);

Is there some way to inject my `jQuery` module/variable to AngularJS and have it not inspect the global namespace?

As you can see my `jquery` module is being exported, so RequireJS will give me a scoped variable when requesting it.

If this isn't possible, what would you do in my situation? What can be done to work around this?

Answer (score 0):

If conventional jQuery globals cause problems, a custom `window` property can be provided for jQuery with [`ng-jq` attrubute](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngJq).

As of today Angular still relies on globals, [jQuery isn't an exception](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.5.0-beta.2/src/Angular.js#L1694).

Answer (score 0):

You could manually [bootstrap](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.bootstrap) the application from requirejs once jQuery is loaded and provide it in a service.

```
requirejs(['jquery'], function (jQuery) {
    angular.module('HelloApp').
    service('jQuery', function () {
        return jQuery.noConflict();
    });
    angular.bootstrap(document, ['HelloApp']);
});
```

Note that you will not include ng-app in the html markup

```js
requirejs.config({
    "baseUrl": "js/lib",
        "paths": {
        "jquery": "//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min",
    }
});

angular.module('HelloApp', []).
controller('HelloController', [function (jQuery) {
    var HelloController = this;
    HelloController.greet = function () {
        return "Hello from HelloController!";
    }

}]).
directive('anoyatron', ['jQuery',function (jQuery) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element) {
            function anoyatron(){
              jQuery(element).slideUp(function(){jQuery(element).slideDown(anoyatron);});   
            }
            anoyatron();
        }
    };
}]);
requirejs(['jquery'], function (jQuery) {
    angular.module('HelloApp').
    service('jQuery', function () {
        return jQuery.noConflict();
    });
    angular.bootstrap(document, ['HelloApp']);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/require.js/2.1.22/require.min.js"></script>
<div ng-controller="HelloController as HelloController">
    <p>{{HelloController.greet()}}</p>
</div>
<div anoyatron>lorem ipsum</div>
```